# why nidda every month and its purpose?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, niddah

Am afraid if my question is impolite and not acceptable under terms of this site but I also think that it is important to know the truth so. I would like to know more about 
 why do women have menstruation every month and not men is their something related to curse(H" forbid) to women due to khava sin. And why nidda is observed ?

Comment: What do you mean by Jewish purity?

Comment: "and also why do women have mensturation every month" Are you asking why there is a Torah law that affect women every month, or why God chose to design the species that way. Regarding the latter, note that other primates, as well as some other species undergo similar cycles. Are you asking why the cycle is the length that it is? Consider clarifying .

Comment: If what you mean by important is that it is one of the few still commonly practiced, please edit.

Comment: When you say "impolite" or "unacceptable under terms of this site," note just about every question in the [tag:sexuality] tag. To quote the Mishnah in Avos, he who is embarrassed cannot learn. If one is afraid to ask, he cannot learn the answer.